# ¿Cómo imprimir en una sola lista varios elementos de un XML?

Tags: java, xml, arraylist

He estado intentando desplegar una SOLA lista con un ArrayList varios elementos que tomo de un XML, pero no logro hacer que funcione, este mi codigo con el XML aun sin implementar ArrayList.

```
public class XMLConceptos {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        File xmlFile = new File("C:\\XML\\conceptos.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

        NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName("Pieza");
        NodeList list2 = document.getElementsByTagName("OperacionPintura");
        NodeList list3 = document.getElementsByTagName("OperacionManoObra");

        for(int i=0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
         Node node = list.item(i);

         if(node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

          Element element = (Element) node;
          Concepto concepto = new Concepto();
              concepto.setPosicion(element.getElementsByTagName("Posicion").item(0).getTextContent());
              concepto.setNumeroParte(element.getElementsByTagName("NumeroParte").item(0).getTextContent());
              concepto.setDescripcion(element.getElementsByTagName("Descripcion").item(0).getTextContent());
              concepto.setMonto(element.getElementsByTagName("Monto").item(0).getTextContent());
              concepto.setCambioPrecio(element.getElementsByTagName("CambioPrecio").item(0).getTextContent());



              System.out.println(concepto.toString());
    }
}
        /*Hay una manera para imprimir una lis*/
        for(int j=0; j < list2.getLength(); j++) {
             Node node2 = list2.item(j);

             if(node2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

              Element element2 = (Element) node2;
              Concepto concepto = new Concepto();
                  concepto.setPosicion(element2.getElementsByTagName("Posicion").item(0).getTextContent());
                  concepto.setDescripcion(element2.getElementsByTagName("Descripcion").item(0).getTextContent());
                  concepto.setUT(element2.getElementsByTagName("UT").item(0).getTextContent());
                  concepto.setMonto(element2.getElementsByTagName("Monto").item(0).getTextContent());

                  System.out.println(concepto.toString1());
        }
    }

        for(int k=0; k < list3.getLength(); k++) {
             Node node3 = list3.item(k);

             if(node3.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

              Element element3 = (Element) node3;

              Concepto concepto = new Concepto();

                  concepto.setUT(element3.getElementsByTagName("UT").item(0).getTextContent());
                  concepto.setMonto(element3.getElementsByTagName("Monto").item(0).getTextContent()); 

                  System.out.println(concepto.toString2());

        }
    }

        }
}
```

e que manera podria colocar un ArrayList para que me imprima todos los elementos que empece con cada ciclo, gracias!!

Comment: No hay forma de probarlo objetivamente, sin tu xml nos dificultas ayudarte. Por favor asegúrate de incluir todos los elementos mencionados en tu pregunta para que siempre tenga un [mcve]

Comment: Adicionalmente list1, list2, y list3 ya son listas, bien podrías ahorrarte el agregar objetos en la lista usando la función `map` de `Stream` e imprimir como te dijeron: `list.stream().map(new Concepto(element.getElementsByTagName("Posicion").item(0).getTextContent(), ...)).forEach(System.out::println);` y así reducir a pocas líneas todo tu código

Answer (score 0):

un gusto saludarte, si mal no entiendo necesitas cargar en un arrayList varios elementos del XML. Podrias inicializar un arrayList de tipo Concepto(**List conceptosXml = new ArrayList<>()**;) y en cada ciclo en donde se obtienen los elementos e ir cargando de esta manera

> conceptosXml.add(concepto);

Y al final para imprimir todos los elementos que hayas cargado podes utilizar el api stream de java

> conceptosXml.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

Espero que te sirva, si es otro el inconveniente podrias ser mas especifico para intentar ayudarte ! Saludos